# xterm.js@3.14.5 can not display anything sometimes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, xtermjs

I use `Xterm@3.14.5` in Vue, but it doesn't display words in it's rendered interface. I also found that when I resize the browser, it shows.it happens very very accidental.

what you have already tried. I find it's documented and check dom. I found that I can gain data before I call `xterm.js's` write function and the data is written.I also check the dom and it renders some empty lines, but when I resize the browser, it rerenders those empty lines.it seems like that my data has entered a queue in xterm, but sometimes it doesn't trigger dom render.